# How to download video content off of Facebook with Ubuntu?

Tags: video, downloads, facebook

How can I download and save videos on Facebook to a file only my computer?  I'm using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

When you want to download a video from Facebook, replace the WWW with m http://m.facebook.com/video  You can then save the video by back clicking on it.

Comment: still working in 2020

Answer (score 5):

Simply install youtube-dl

```
apt-get install youtube-dl
```

and then use it..

```
$ youtube-dl "https://www.facebook.com/RashiVatsFOX26/videos/vb.1412789925606762/1769215369964214/?type=2&theater"
[facebook] 1769215369964214: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: Love donuts Check this out!!!-1769215369964214.mp4
[download] 100% of 53.47MiB in 00:14
```

Comment: Youtube-dl will no longer work for Facebook.  Looking for another option.

Comment: Works for me, at first it failed because I have 2FA on Facebook, but you can resolve this by using the --cookies option. Minimum fuss way to get the cookies file is to install the [cookies.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg) extension (for Chrome, others exist) and use it to download the cookies as a file. then plug it directly to youtube-dl --cookies file.txt and add the Facebook video url (don't forget to use the Video URL and not the post URL)

Answer (score 2):

[Video DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) works well with Firefox.  I don't know about Chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Download Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-helper/fkjlohfdjcjhmfcabomglnciodlnplhk).  Its an add-on extension to Chrome.  It can be downloaded from here, and through the extensions add-on under the  tools menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Video Downloader - Chrome Web Store](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pFxMYJLPlZSHGThJFzIl0cCoz87q02GnyQC_hXeQo43JuAvh2bzATCNTJ2WSwPj9R5J7VSeWyfg=s640-h400-e365-rw) worked for me.

I couldn't find "Download Helper" as noted by Mitch - might be gone now.